Trouble integrating Dear ImGui as Separeted project; using Premake - "imgui.h" file cannot be found
Edit: I change the main topic to "integrating imgui as StaticLib|SharedLib"
Currently, I'm encountering difficulties integrating Dear ImGui as StaticLib into my C++ project using Premake as the build system.
I have integrated other libraries, such as GLFW (from the system), Glad, ViennaCL, and Eigen, using the same pattern that I'm applying for Dear ImGui. When calling useImGUI("opengl3", "GLFW"), it compiles successfully. However, when attempting to integrate ImGui as a separate project and then link it, an error occurs.
../src/main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: imgui.h: Nonexistent file or directory
   10 | #include "imgui.h"

Data:
├── build
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── MyProject.make
│   └── obj
├── cr.sh
├── include
│   └── test.hpp
├── premake.lua
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── test.cpp
└── vendor
    ├── boost
    ├── eigen
    ├── glad
    ├── glfw
    ├── imgui
    ├── premake.lua
    └── viennaCL

premake.lua (main)
this works
dofile "vendor/premake.lua"

workspace "MeuProjeto"
    -- foo

project "glad"
    -- foo

project "MeuProjeto"
    -- foo
    
    useEigen()
    useViennaCL()
    useImGUI("opengl3", "glfw")
    useGLFW()
    useBoost('accumulators')

    links { "glad" }

this not works
dofile "vendor/premake.lua"

workspace "MeuProjeto"
    -- foo

project "glad"
    -- foo

project "imgui"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    useImGUI("opengl3", "glfw")

project "MeuProjeto"
    -- foo
    
    useEigen()
    useViennaCL()
    useGLFW()
    links { "imgui" }
    useBoost('accumulators')

    links { "glad" }

this not works too
project "MeuProjeto"
    -- foo
    
    useEigen()
    useViennaCL()
    useGLFW()
    useImGUI("opengl3", "glfw")
    useBoost('accumulators')

    links { "glad" }

defs
function useImGUI(...)
    local targets = {...}
    for _, target in ipairs(targets) do
        files {
            "vendor/imgui/*.cpp",
            "vendor/imgui/*.h",
            "vendor/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_" .. target .. "*",
        }
    end

    externalincludedirs { "vendor/imgui", "vendor/imgui/backends" }
end


Showing your premake5.lua might help, especially the part where you call the function.

The way I have integrated Imgui is to compiled it as a lib and then link the lib to the main project..
Imgui->Premake5.lua
project "ImGui"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    staticruntime "off"
targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files
{
    "imconfig.h",
    "imgui.h",
    "imgui.cpp",
    "imgui_draw.cpp",
    "imgui_internal.h",
    "imgui_tables.cpp",
    "imgui_widgets.cpp",
    "imstb_rectpack.h",
    "imstb_textedit.h",
    "imstb_truetype.h",
    "imgui_demo.cpp"
}

.....
And then link it in main project workspace..
Workspace "apllication_workspace"
    architecture "x64"

configurations
{
    "Debug",
    "Release",
    "Dist"
}


include "vendor/imgui"
<other premake libs>

project "Application"
    location " Application"
 
   includedirs
    {
        "vendor/imgui",
         <other libs>
     }
    links
    {
        "GLFW",
        "Glad",
        "ImGui"
    }

